# .htaccess Redirect Conditions not working on Apache 2.2

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have some URLs in the following format:

```
www.website.co.uk/form.aspx?type=brochure
www.website.co.uk/form.aspx?type=contact
www.website.co.uk/form.aspx?type=quote
```

I need to redirect each one to a different page based on the 'type' parameter.

My understanding of rewrites is that you would use a rewrite condition to pick up this parameter followed by a redirect rule, e.g.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^type=contact [NC]
Redirect 301 /form.aspx /customer-support/contact-us?

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^type=quote [NC]
Redirect 301 /form.aspx /ask-an-expert?
```

This works on the redirect tester I am using (http://www.urlitor.com/) but not on the actual site.

I think this could be related to the version of Apache I'm running (2.2) - this can't be upgraded as it is a requirement of Magento 2.

Is this possible? Any tips would be highly appreciated - many thanks.

Comment: In the vhost have you allowed your `.htaccess` file to set `mod_rewrite` settings? You should have `AllowOverride FileInfo` or `AllowOverride All` within the `<Directory>`section of the vhost.

Comment: You don't want `Redirect 301` but a `RewriteRule` there : http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: `<If "%{QUERY_STRING} =~ /^type=quote/i"> Redirect 301 .... </If>`

Answer (score 0):

I think you're mixing up Apache packages, `RewriteCond` is part of `mod_rewrite` whereas `Redirect` is `mod_alias` - you should use `RewriteCond` with `RewriteRule` - like so:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/form.aspx [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^type=contact [NC]
RewriteRule .* /customer-support/contact-us? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/form.aspx [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^type=quote [NC]
RewriteRule .* /ask-an-expert? [R=301,L]
```

[Online test at htaccess.mwl.be](http://htaccess.mwl.be?share=b5d2fcad-d655-5137-8d77-b95012a13767)

---

**However** since this is Magento 2, it's important that these rules are added before Magento's core router (line 172 in a vanilla .htaccess), if you're adding them to the root `.htaccess` file:

```
############################################
## add your custom rewrites before line 172
## which is the start of Magento's core router

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/form.aspx [NC]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^type=contact [NC]
    RewriteRule .* /customer-support/contact-us? [R,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/form.aspx [NC]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^type=quote [NC]
    RewriteRule .* /ask-an-expert? [R,L]

############################################ < this would have been line 172
## never rewrite for existing files, directories and links

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
```

(this works on my local Magento 2 dev install)

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me - that's very helpful.

The problem is that we don't support the 'QSD' flag which seems necessary here - adding that brings the site down.

Are there any workarounds?

Comment: You're right, yeah, sorry - `QSD` is Apache 2.4+ you can use the `?` trick ... I'm just checking whether you can use `[NC]` on the `RewriteCond` rather than `RewriteRule`.

Comment: I *think* that's got the flags sorted out now... missed off `R=301` (you can use 302 for temporary redirects) from the `RewriteRule` initially.

Comment: Thanks but again it seems that the 'AND' flag isn't supported as this also brings the site down. Removing it causes the redirect not to trigger.

Comment: Dowp - my bad `[AND]` doesn't exist - it's implicit... I'm obviously nicotine deprived atm or something :|

Comment: Thanks for the reply again. This is what I'm trying, which works on the test tool but not on our server annoyingly.

    1 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/form.aspx [NC] This condition was met.
    2 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^type=contact [NC] This condition was met.
    3 RewriteRule . /customer-support/contact-us? [R=301,L] The new url is http://www.website.co.uk/customer-support/contact-us
Test are stopped, a redirect will be made with status code 301

Comment: ... hang on, this is Magento 2 you say ...? Have you put these rewrites in the root `.htaccess` file ... and are they **before** line 175? (that block is the core rewrite router)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144848/discussion-between-jkhamler-and-cd001).

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^type=contact [NC]
RewriteRule ^form.aspx  /customer-support/contact-us? [R]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^type=quote [NC]
RewriteRule ^form.aspx  /ask-an-expert? [R]
```